# Execute jquery if javascript variable is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

i have a javascript (!) code which i use to detect Safari browser:

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
```

It works perfectly. Now when that `isSafari` variable is `true` I want to execute some jquery (NOT javascript!) code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
some jquery here doing some jquery stuff
...
```

plus if that variable `isSafari` is `false` i want to execute different jquery (!) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    some other different jquery code here doing other jquery stuff
    ........
```

I tried simple javascript if/else statement but it seems it executes both jquery codes every time, it's like it doesn't eat the if/else at all.

I think i need some syntax to 'merge' it or something, couldn't find anything on the net.

Thanks!

---

Edit: So here is whole code:

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"


//accordion
$(document).ready(function(){

  if (isSafari) {

$('.module-desc').hide();
$('.accordion > h4').click(function(){ 
        $('.accordion').find('.module-desc').hide('fast'); 
        var thisBlock = $(this).parent().index('.accordion');
        $('.accordion').find('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('activeToggle').siblings()   
.removeClass('activeToggle').children('.module-desc').hide('fast');
        return false;       

    });


  } else {

    $('.module-desc').hide();
$('.accordion > h4').click(function(){ 
        $('.accordion').find('.module-desc').hide('fast'); 
        var thisBlock = $(this).parent().index('.accordion');
        $('.accordion').find('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('activeToggle').siblings()   
.removeClass('activeToggle').children('.module-desc').hide('fast');
        return false;       

    });
    $('.accordion').click(function(){ 
      if (isSafari == false) {
        $('.accordion').find('.module-desc').hide('fast'); 
        var thisBlock = $(this).index('.accordion');
        $('.accordion').find('.active').not($(this.children('h4'))).removeClass('active');
        $(this).children('h4').toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).toggleClass('activeToggle').siblings()   
.removeClass('activeToggle').children().children('.module-desc').hide('fast');
        return false;       
      };
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: "*when that `isSafari` variable is `true` I want to execute some [jQuery] (NOT [JavaScript]!) code*" - but jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: Thought that too but it seems that just doesn't work this way. If i use if/else for those 2 parts of code both of them gets executed every time no matter what - its tottaly ignoring if isSafari is true or not. if there is like 'document.write("hello yes its safari")' and 'no its not safari' there is absolutely no problem it works as expected.

Comment: Can you show us your (attempted) `if`/`else` code? And explain what you want to happen when `isSafari` is `true`/`false`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking a pretty basic `if/else` question:

```
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (isSafari) {
        $("#result").html("Yeah Found Safari!");
    } else {
        $("#result").html("Not Safari");
    }
});
```

This will most certainly never execute both branches of the `if/else`.

If you mean to ask more than this, then please explain further or show us your exact code that doesn't work.

---

FYI: All jQuery is Javascript.  Javascript is the language.  jQuery is a library written in Javascript.